# Fatal error: Call to undefined method TwitterOAuth::getRequestToken()

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I'm working with Abraham's `twitteroauth` to implement Twitter OAuth in my application. While running my application, this is the error I'm encountering:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method TwitterOAuth::getRequestToken() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tmhOAuth-master/login_twitter.php on line 12
```

login_twitter.php

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once('config.php');
// new file, I have saved my app's key and secret in config.php

require("twitteroauth.php");

$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
// Requesting authentication tokens, the parameter is the URL we will be redirected to callback url
$request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken('http://localhost/tmhOAuth-master/get_twitter_tokens.php');

// Saving them into the session

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];


// If everything goes well..
if ($twitteroauth->http_code == 200) {
    // Let's generate the URL and redirect
    $url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']);

    header('Location: ' . $url);
} else {
    // It's a bad idea to kill the script, but we've got to know when there's an error.
    die('Something wrong happened.');
}

?>
```

What seems to be wrong with the `getRequestToken()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method has been replaced with the oauth method. Please read through the sign in flow for the current method names. https://twitteroauth.com

Check the issue here https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/issues/321.